# Div moves only when zooming out

Tags: html, css, move

I did a quick search on stackoverflow and found some ways to solve it but none works.
I have my HTML code like below:

```
<div id="product_box">
    <div id="pro_img"><img src="images.jpg'" width="140px"/></div>
    <div id="pro_text">

    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
<style>
    #product_box {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #8dd5f6;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 196px;
    float:left;
    }

    #pro_text{
    float:left;
    width:189px; 
    height: 196px;     
    background-color: #CCC;
    }

    #pro_img {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #8dd5f6;
    width:140px;
    height: 196px;  
    }
</style>
```

The `#pro_img` is to the left and  `#pro_text` is to the right, it works fine at default zoom and large zoom in but the problem is that when I zoom out the pro_text (right div) falls off the container box.
I found someone says that I need `box-sizing: border-box;` inside of my CSS. I tried it and put it like this:

```
<style>
    #pro_img {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #8dd5f6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:140px;
    height: 196px;  
    }
</style>
```

It won't fall off anymore but the border is invisible as it border the image from inside.

I disable the `border-right` from `#pro_img`, the problem's gone but I want a `border-right` that would separate the image and the text.

Total `width` needed: `140(img)+1(border)+189(text) = 330px` just fit the container box. I tried increase box width to `332px` but it won't help.

Thank you.

Comment: ...for starters try removing he `'` in your `<img src="images.jpg'" width="140px"/>` :)

Comment: @NoobEditior but what if the `'` is in the file name ^^

Comment: @NoobEditor oops, sorry, it was my mistake when editing the code here. it's not the problem :D

Comment: @S.Visser : going by current mark - then it wont be rendered as an image! :)

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are using float:left I cleared that used margin instead see this http://jsfiddle.net/3pmmjLx8/

## UPDATED CSS CODE

```
#pro_text{
margin-left:141px;
width:189px; 
height: 196px;     
background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: if I don't use float left, it will completely falls off no matter zoom it is.